# Is google-service.json now obligatory?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

Is google-service.json now obligatory ?

In my android app I have added google map and gcm. Now I'm migrating project from eclipse to android studio and I have some little problem.

I have already created a key for gcm, how can I create manually the google-service.json starting from my existing key ?

Another question is :
Initially to add the google play services into my app I followed this official guide :
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

But without this code lines (that I found on stackoverflow):

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

the compiler had not found the play service. Why google doesn't tell nothing about this code line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs I'd say yes, it's needed. If you follow the line guide you can download a json file even you have already created your project in the developer console. There is a "configuration file" button [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start). In addition the lines you see "apply plugin" and "classpath" are only for Android Studio (the official IDE). Using the setup suggested it's really easy to setup the project with Android Studio.

Comment: Ok. But where does google says that we have to include apply plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' and
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2' ?

Comment: THis code line is mandatory for all of google play services , right ? 
Because I'm trying to use only google maps services without "apply plugin 'com.google.gms.google-services' and classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'  ; but when I try to import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint; android studio gives me the following error :
"cannot resolve symbols maps"

Comment: No it's needed only for GCM, however it's out of scope for this question. If you want you can post another question. Accept the reply if it's ok for you.

Comment: Thanks. I will open new question. However with that gradles code lines the errors disappears ..

Comment: Remember to accept questions. Stackoverflow is not a forum.